# Mysqli prepared statement stmt_num_rows returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

For some reason `stmt_num_rows` always ends up being 0. No matter if I execute the query with the correct email and word or the wrong one. 
This is the code:

```
    include_once './Connect.php';

$db = new DB_Connect(); 
$con = $db->connect();

$password = $_POST["Password"]; 
$email = $_POST["Email"];  
$word = $_POST["Word"]; 
$true = 'true';  
$false = 'false';
$response = array();


$selectquery = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Email = ? AND Word = ?");  
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selectquery , "ss" , $email , $word); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($selectquery); 
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($selectquery); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectquery, $ID);


    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($selectquery) > 0){ 
        $response[resp] = $true; 
        $updatequery = mysqli_prepare($con , "UPDATE users SET Password = ? WHERE Email = ? AND Word = ?"); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updatequery ,"sss", $password, $email, $word); 
        mysqli_stmt_execute($updatequery); 
        mysqli_stmt_close($updatequery);
    }else{
        $response[resp] = $false; 
    }


echo json_encode($response); 
mysqli_stmt_close($selectquery); 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Run down of the code: *Password*, *Email* and *Word* are posted from android. First there is a query to check if there is a user (row) in the table with the corresponding Email and Word. If that is true the ID is added. Then `stmt_num_rows` is called to check the number of rows fetched, yet the number of rows that is fetched ends up being 0 (I get a response as "false"). But if it was one then the UPDATE query would be called and I would receive a response "true". Does anyone know the mistake I've made?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try running the query in the database directly for testing purposes?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Try using [`mysqli_stmt_store_result();`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) before using `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`

Comment: 'resp' is undefined, you need to debug this more , add logging

Comment: No I have not, but I did run both queries separately and they work fine. There's something wrong in the way i store the results I believe. I'm checking the link right now Fred. I do have mysqli_stmt_store_result();

Comment: If you're not using the results of the `SELECT` query, you might as well just run `SELECT 1 FROM...` and check for any results.

Comment: You may not even need to use `mysqli_stmt_store_result` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`. Try removing / commenting those out and try it again. If that fails, then your POSTs may be failing. Check for errors against those and variables, and in your query.

Comment: Fred you were right the issue wasn't in the php it was actually the data posted. Since I'm using the Async Http library i forgot to post the actual parameters I want to send. I set the params to null.

Comment: also make sure that no whitespace is being introduced, if so, `trim()` and do a var_dump. Remember that POST arrays are case-sensitive. `Password` and `password` etc. are two different animals. Same goes for the other POST arrays.

Comment: ah great. Glad to hear it was resolved @IvanJavorovic *cheers*

Comment: Yes, thank you so much :)

Comment: @IvanJavorovic I decided to use our comments to close the question with, and submitted an answer below if you wish to accept it and mark it as solved. Otherwise, others may think it hasn't been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting our comments to an answer to close this with:

Mine:

> *"Try removing / commenting those out and try it again. If that fails, then your POSTs may be failing. Check for errors against those and variables, and in your query."*

and:

> *"also make sure that no whitespace is being introduced, if so, `trim()` and do a var_dump. Remember that POST arrays are case-sensitive. `Password` and `password` etc. are two different animals. Same goes for the other POST arrays"*

Ivan's:

> *"Fred you were right the issue wasn't in the php it was actually the data posted. Since I'm using the Async Http library i forgot to post the actual parameters I want to send. I set the params to null"*

---

**Passwords**

I noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or crypt, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.